# How do i access CodeCommit in a separate account from Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

i am currently trying to implement an Amplify Solution, having a CodeCommit repository in separate Deployment Account and initializing the Amplify resources in the environment (Sandbox) account. As far the setup works with initializig the amplify project in a separate accout. But when i try to add hosting to Amplify, it wants me to connect to my CodeCommit repository. But i cant see any repositories since they are not in the same account. Up to now I tried various approaches with cross-account permissions/policies to allow my account access to CodeCommit in the deployment account but nothing seems to work.
It seems every solution to access CodeCommit in another account works with assuming a role, but since Amplify wants me to choose the Repo in the UI i cannot assume a role. There seems to be an open issue on Github, yet no response there..
Is there any way to make this run?

Greetings,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received answer from the aws support. Currently it is just not possible/supported. This feature is planned and the feature request https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/64 is already approved.